# Probabilities Of Rank : Lottery Odds

Tags: probability-distributions, permutations, lotteries

There are 5 ping pong balls labelled with numbers 1-5 which will be placed in a lottery machine.  During the event, the 5 balls will be drawn and arrive to a combination.  The participant that has the combination drawn first wins the top prize, the next unique participant with a matching combination is given the second prize, and so on with the final participant receiving the fourth prize.

Before the lottery, all participants are assigned combinations (out of the 120 possible unique permutations).

I entered a lottery, and have acquired 59 combinations of the 120 unique permutations which can be made from pulling ping pong balls numbered 1 to 5 from a lottery machine.  There are only 4 participants, and we have the following amount of the available 120 unique number combinations (no overlap between participants):

Entrant A has 59 combinations,
Entrant B has 41 combinations,
Entrant C has 13 combinations,
Entrant D has 7 combinations,

Once a participant has a combination drawn, they are removed from the lottery and cannot take a further place in the order.  I am running into issues determining the odds I end up with a combination which is pulled 3rd or 4th, as Python is not accurately running currently and I am therefore unable to create a Plackett-Luce model code to determine the overall probability per participant per place.  Is there a more direct process to obtaining the odds for each participant to end up with ranks 1, 2, 3 & 4?

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  Does each entrant "have" distinct permutations or might there be some overlap?  And then, how does the lottery work?  Are random permutations selected with or without replacement?

Comment: Hi Lulu - thanks for requesting the clarification.  I wasnt aware how lacking in context it was until I read your comment.  Ive been so deep in trying to answer it I forget not everyone else has been up to their ears in the process.  I made some edits to provide more context, but for quick response: each permutation is unique, so Entrant A has 59 of the 120 possible unique combinations and no Entrant shares any combination with another. Random permutations are selected without replacement.

Comment: So, the permutations are selected with replacement, it seems.  Not sure that has any impact on the probabilities but it certainly would have an impact on how many rounds the lottery may require.

Comment: To your question:  Since the participants have differing numbers of permutations, I think you're stuck with case work.  But it's not that bad since the number of participants is small.  Just enumerate the possible cases for the first $3$ (since knowing the first $3$ determines the $4^{th}$.  It should be possible with paper and pencil (if a bit tedious).  Simulation is easy, of course, and should be fast if an approximate solution suffices (which is usually the case for problems like these).

Comment: To speed the calculations, note that you can ignore all the permutations which belong to an eliminated player.  Thus, if $A$ is eliminated first, we may assume that we are now drawing from $120-59=61$ total permutations.  Thus, in this scenario, the probability that $B$ wins next is $\frac {41}{61}$.